# How to get the data from CSV file

Tags: bash

I have a CSV file below the records. Based on the awk condition if the Status Column value is less than 30, Then the respective Project (Column1) value Orange should be printed.

```
awk -F'[,]'  '{ if ( 30 >= 30 ) {print $2,$9} }' user.csv
```

Current output

```
Project Status
Apple "Current (days remaining : 83)"
Orange"Current (days remaining : 30)"
```

Expected output

```
Project
Orange
```

```
ID,Project,"App System",Version,"Report Date",Status
1,Apple,NAT,0,0,0,0,09/02/2022,"Current (days remaining : 83)"
2,Orange,BAT,0,0,0,0,09/02/2022,"Current (days remaining : 30)"
```

can you please someone help me with this?

Comment: The data still doesn't make sense. Your title line doesn't have 9 fields, so why should it print `Status` (which is the 6th field in your example)? Also, why would it exclude the second line, given that your condition `30 >= 30` is mathematically always true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use a shell comparison operator `-le` in `awk` instead of `awk`'s own comparison operator `<=`. Your text describes the requirement as *less than* rather than *less than or equal to*, but your example output shows the latter. Furthermore you've actually got `30` on both sides of the expression instead of comparing a field to the value.

Finally, you need to split the ninth comma-separated field into parts so you can perform the numeric comparison. The colon (`:`) is a convenient separator for this task.

```
awk -F, '{ split($9, c, ":"); if (NR==1 || c[2]+0 <= 30) {print $2} }' user.csv
```

Output

```
Project
Orange
```